# VCenter behind Nginx Proxy Manager comes the error message: HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, vsphere, vcenter

I would like to do the vcenter behind a proxy in the network. we use Nginx proxy manager. I configured the vcenter server in nginx with the advanced configuration

```
sub_filter "VCENTER-FQDN" "EXTERNAL-FQDN"; 
proxy_set_header Host VCENTER-FQDN; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_ssl_verify off; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
proxy_buffering off; 
client_max_body_size 0; 
proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
proxy_redirect https://VCENTER-FQDN/ https://EXTERNAL-FQDN/;
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAzii.png)

the proxy is in a different vlan but has access to VCenter

does anyone know what the problem could be

I configured the vcenter server like here https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/71387

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with vCenter 8.0. On the settings of the proxy host i enabled websocket support. Here's my config for the advanced tab of nginx proxy manager:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host vcenter_hostname;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass https://vcenter_hostname;
}
location /ui/app-fabric/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass https://vcenter_hostname;
}

location /websso/SAML2 {
    sub_filter "vcenter_hostname" "vcenter_proxy_hostname";
    proxy_set_header Host vcenter_hostname;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    proxy_pass https://vcenter_hostname;
}
```